# How to separate user interface for phone and pad (or laptop)

Tags: windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a MainPage.xaml with ListView, it works on phone well, but when it runs in windows 10 laptop, the listView item is very small, and I can't use all the area of screen.
So that I want to use ListView on Phone and GridView with groups on Pad and laptop (larger screen). How can I do that?

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" x:Name="bankListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource banksViewSource}}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="32" Margin="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0" Background="White" Width="30" Height="30">
                    <Image Source="{Binding LogoImage}" Stretch="Fill" />
                </Border>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Margin="10,0,0,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource BankNameStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                    <Grid Width="250">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="25*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding ChangeTime}" Style="{StaticResource BankChangeTimeStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding USD_Buy}" Style="{StaticResource BankBuyStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding USD_Sell}" Style="{StaticResource BankBuyStyle}" MaxHeight="60"/>
                    </Grid>

                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0">
                        <TextBlock Text='{Binding Key}' Foreground="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" FontSize="15" Margin="0" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" Height="400" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, it sounds like you don't actually want to detect "phone" vs "laptop", you want a different layout depending on how big the app's window is (or possibly the screen). Since you can buy ["Desktop" computers with very small screens](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/tablets/hp-stream-7-tablet---5701), and you will soon be able to use ["Phone" devices with very large screens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oi1B9fjVs4), asking what type of thing you are running on is the wrong question.

You should watch [this //build talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2015/2-679) or look at [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210475.aspx) which show how to use new [Adaptive Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.adaptivetrigger.aspx) in XAML to dynamically change your layout based on available window size.